# Oracle issue with concat()

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, string-literals

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, CONCAT(FIRST_NAME," ",LAST_NAME) AS EMPLOYEE_NAME, HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

I tried running the above code and it's giving me error ( invalid number of arguments ) for concatenation. I am trying to add a space between FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME.

Comment: try using ' ' single quotes instead of double ones

Comment: Tried single quotes, sadly same error

Comment: Provide table's DDL as CREATE TABLE script and some sample data as INSERT INTO script. Specify MySQL version (maybe it is 8+? or maybe it is not MySQL at all?). Provide FULL error message.

Comment: this suggests you're using Oracle as DBMS, and getting error code `ORA-00909` . Aren't you ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle as DBMS. Fixed using the || operator

Answer (score 0):

The error you get suggests you're using Oracle as DBMS, but not MySQL, and getting error code `ORA-00909`.

At Most two arguments can be put in the Oracle's `CONCAT()` function, and using double quotes are prohibited within that, single quotes might be used , instead. So, in your case, try to use as

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' '),LAST_NAME) AS EMPLOYEE_NAME, HIRE_DATE
  FROM EMPLOYEES
```

or pipes as concatenetion operators

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS EMPLOYEE_NAME, HIRE_DATE
  FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS EMPLOYEE_NAME, HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Answer (score -1):

it should work if the field names are correct, there is  no syntax errors. if you just want  to add a separator in between the fields, try SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME);

Comment: this was answered before the question was identified as oracle, so valid for MySQL only.